# Are there any patterns for decoupling coupled async data in redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have two container(connected to a redux store) components(say A and B) on a page that both depend on one redux saga to complete for their data.

Currently what I'm doing to avoid two async calls(and to avoid one making the call and have the other check for the data to be there) is to move the async call up into a higher container component C that contains both A and B.

Then I'm converting A and B into normal components(not connected to the store) and passing them props from C.

Is there a pattern out there to achieve this better?
or any migration path to achieve this conversion?
or is it best just to do this change and spend the time moving the async call up to C and convert A and B to standard components?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a pattern out there to achieve this better?

Best practice to prepare data into multiple components and handle their actions is having one root `redux`-provider, which provides all actions and store connection to descending components.
Then, `redux-saga` can intercept any actions and perform API call, since it combination of middleware and process manager. Usually components dispatch only `_REQUEST`-like action, after receiving which `saga` performs batch of async operations and then put `_SUCCESS` of `_FAILURE`-like action to reducers.
Of course, if you want to support optimistical update, `_REQUEST`-like action should be also supported in reducers.

If your components has explicit or implicit link between them, simple action handling via `takeEvery` or `takeLatest` can be not enough. But `saga` simply allows to perform creating multiple async processes, which can accumulate state in local closure before `yield`-based loop.

```
function * manyActionsSaga() {
    let flowPromise = Promise.resolve();
    while(true) {
        const action = yield take(['ACTION_1', 'ACTION_2', 'ACTION_3']);
        yield call(() => flowPromise)
        flowPromise = flowPromise.then(() => {
            // Similar event handling
        })
    }
}
```